# Shorthand characters in section titles (Xe(La)TeX)

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex

I have learnt how to define shorthands by the commands

```
\useshorthands{(a character, e.g. ')}
```

in the preamble and

```
\defineshorthand{(shorthand code)}{(expansion)}
```

just after `\begin{document}`, e.g. `\defineshorthand{'a}{apple`} to get `«'a»` typesetted into `«apple»`. Trouble is, when I try to put a shorthand character (in my case, the apostrophe `'`) in the title of a section, subsection, subsubsection or chapter and combine that with the table of contents, I get an error message apparently related to the toc file.
All of that, naturally, after creating a command `\newcommand{\6}{'\Gr{}}`, where `\Gr` is a font family of the same font as the default font, a command created to avoid the typesetting of shorthands which are not supposed to be shorthands, as 'a turns to apple in any context, even if it's ' a with a blank in the middle. Therefore the section title contains the command `\6`. Why does that happen and how do I solve it?

For example the error is produced with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\useshorthands{'}

\begin{document}  
\defineshorthand{'a}{apple}  

\section{Un'\,arpa}  
\tableofcontents  

\end{document}
```

The error produced is:

```
.mu2.toc:2: Missing $ inserted.  
<inserted text>  
$  
l.2 ...t@token \egroup \Gr {}arpa}{1}  
{section.0.1}  

?
```

and the full .toc file reads:

```
\select@language {italian}  
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {0.1}Un^\bgroup 
    \prime \futurelet \@let@token \egroup \,arpa}{1}
```

the last two lines being one line together.

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is really needed.

Comment: Please, add to your question and not in comments; there should also be something producing the error.

Comment: Sorry, but the example is far from minimal. By the way what's the meaning of `\newcommand\€{\Gr{ }}`? I can guess none.

Comment: \€ was probably meant to be a quick way to reset the font after using, say, \Chs. After e.g. \Chs{我爱上你了。}, the font gets stuck to the \Chs font, so \€ was way to not have to explicitly type \Gr{ } to change the font. Btw the full line from the .toc file is \contentsline {section}{\numberline {0.1}Un^\bgroup \prime \futurelet \@let@token \egroup \Gr {}arpa}{1}{section.0.1}.

Comment: Sorry, but I won't try that example; I don't have the fonts and it's too complex. You should try reducing it.

Comment: Reduced. \Chs can also be removed, I left it for the reference in the comment.

Comment: Is this question ever going to get answered? I'll reduce the example even more, though that forces me to remove something the comments make reference to.

Comment: The example you make doesn't show any error.

Comment: On my computer it does. That IS strange…

Comment: Please, add to your question information about your TeX distribution and version of `babel`.

Comment: I don't know. I can tell you the help for the package was «Printed November 16, 2011», and has a section called «3 Changes in Babel version 3.7», and I work on TeXShop version 3.26, recently updated. Is that enough?

Comment: Install the most recent MacTeX (with TeX Live 2013) and run TeX Live utility, so you'll have an up-to-date system. Then try again.

Comment: Indeed the error has vanished. Now let me try with a longer document. OK gone. Probably a bug of an old version of TeX. But why does putting the shorthand character at the end of a section title generate the error `\user@active@arg' has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.7971 \sect{Finiamo'}
                      
?`? Is TeX trying to expand something that isn't there? I guess so, because adding \Gr{} right after it (\Gr being a font family previously defined as Times New Roman) solves the problem.

Comment: I'd avoid new shorthand characters; what's the *real* usage of `'`?

Comment: What do you mean _new_ shorthand characters and _real_ usage? The `'` is used as an apostrophe, as in "it's", which would seem unlikely in a title, but in Italian there are elisions like "l'arpa", "the harp", where the article "la" fuses with "arpa" losing the vowel, or there is "un po'", "a little", where "po'" is short for "poco". Thinking on it, using `'` as shorthand character is that characters like ± are not allowed without XeTeX: the error is in the comment below. XeTeX is too slow compiling for taking notes.

Comment: ./mu19.tex:4: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 \useshorthands{±}

Comment: I know well how the apostrophe is used in Italian, which is my mother tongue too. And I've never felt any need to define it in any special way. Just type `'` where an apostrophe is used in Italian and don't worry.

Comment: What do you mean defining it in a special way?

Comment: *YOU* have `\useshorthands{'}` and then some definition for it. I asked for the *real* definition of the shorthand, you didn't answer.

Comment: `\dsh{'d}{derivat}
\dsh{'p}{parzial}
\dsh{'i}{infinitesim}
\dsh{"i}{infinit}
\dsh{'g}{gradient}
\dsh{'G}{Jacobiano}
\dsh{"G}{Matrice Jacobiana}
\dsh{'D}{total}
\dsh{"d}{differenzial}
\dsh{"D}{differenziabil}
\dsh{'f}{funzion}
\dsh{'m}{multivariat}
\dsh{'I}{integr}
\dsh{'s}{spazi}
\dsh{"m}{metric}
\dsh{'c}{continu}
\dsh{'a}{accumulazione}
\dsh{'l}{limit}
\dsh{'e}{equazion}
\dsh{"p}{punt}`
was what I had, given that `\dsh` is defined as `\defineshorthand`.

Comment: You can think this is useful, but you'll soon discover it isn't: it clutters your document with incomprehensible stuff. In a few weeks you'll not remember what `'e` means.

Comment: That's one of the reasons I decided to drop shorthands, the others being the problem of this question which now is solved, and the expansion of non-shorthands (un po' di -> un poderivati). Right now I resolved to only define a few "command shorthands" like \CR for Corpo Rigido which is very common and immediately understandable. In any case it doesn't do any harm since I don't study on the source but on the typesetted pdf.

Comment: In any case the question will be closable once someone tells me (if possible) why an apostrophe has to become something as complicated as `^\bgroup \prime \futurelet \@let@token \egroup`, and what those backslashed things (`\prime` excepted) mean. The practical issue is fixed with the TeX Live update, the theoretical issue is what I just asked. Once both are fixed, this question is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `'` as a shorthand character to begin with. Period.

Why do you get that strange behavior? It's a bit complicated, but I'll try anyway.

1. Some characters may be “active”, so that they behave like macros; the main example is `~`. Also Babel shorthand prefixes become active.
2. Some characters may be “math active”, which means that they behave like macros in math mode only, while they remain unexpandable. The main example is the ASCII apostrophe `'`, which in math mode becomes mostly equivalent to typing `^{\prime}`.
3. Section titles are “moving arguments”: they are saved in a special place and macros inside them are expanded when writing in the `.aux` file. Active characters are expanded, math active ones aren't.
4. When Babel activates a shorthand prefix, it makes sure that it behaves in the same way as before it became a shorthand prefix when not followed by a defined combination.
5. If you have `\useshorthands{'}`, the apostrophe becomes active.
6. If you have `\section{Un'\,arpa}`, when the `.aux` file is written out, the token `'` is expanded.
7. The combination `'\,` isn't defined as a shorthand, so LaTeX uses whatever meaning was assigned to `'` as active character before it was defined as a shorthand character.
8. The expansion of `'` in math mode (when active) is `^\bgroup\prim@s`.
9. The tokens `^` and `\bgroup` aren't expandable; the expansion of `\prim@s` is

   ```
   \prime\futurelet\@let@token\pr@m@s
   ```
10. The first three tokens above are unexpandable, the last one is and becomes

    ```
    \ifx'\@let@token
      \expandafter\pr@@@s
    \else
      \ifx^\@let@token
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@t
      \else
        \egroup
      \fi
    \fi
    ```

    and, at this point, things are not really predictable, because `\let@token` can be anything. In your case it isn't equivalent to `'`, so the false branch is followed and `\let@token` isn't equivalent to `^` either, so `\egroup` is produced, which is unexpandable.
11. Result: in the `.aux` file you find gibberish, precisely

    ```
    Un^\bgroup \prime \futurelet \@let@token \egroup \,arpa
    ```

    but you might find other results, depending on what `\@let@token` happened to be.

Comment: Uh-huh. I guess `\fi` ends an `\ifx`, right? And what does that gibberish mean? I mean, if those expansions take place, the resulting tokens must have some kind of a meaning, at least to TeX, right? And any idea why that caused problems with TeX Live 2012?

Comment: @MickG Yes, they have a meaning, but it's completely useless in that situation. It's just an untimely expansion caused by your programming error.

Comment: So let me get this straight: using `'` as a shorthand character makes it behave as though it were in math mode whenever it is not in a shorthand sequence, therefore resulting in the `.aux`'s gibberish. Is that right? So the gibberish is the normal expansion of `'` in math mode? And what does that gibberish mean when it isn't useless - e.g. in math mode (?) -? And what other characters must simply ***not*** be used as shorthand characters in your opinion?

Comment: @MickG Use none, other than `"` (that's already used).

Comment: In what sense is `"` "already used" as a shorthand character? And what about the other questions in the comment above?

Comment: `texdoc babel`. As for the other questions: those tokens mean something, but not in that context, where they appear because you're using wrongly the shorthand mechanism.

Comment: In what context do they mean something and what do they mean?

Comment: @MickG http://profs.sci.univr.it/~gregorio/introtex.pdf page 93